# Font of Moderator Agreement is too small (especially on mobile)

Tags: bug, status-review, design, accessibility, moderator-agreement

For some reason, the font size on the [Moderator Agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement) page is too small compared to other articles under /legal, the Help Center, or other text throughout the sites in general.

This is true for desktop and mobile but at least on desktop, one could zoom in a little bit. Technically, you could zoom on mobile too but you lose responsiveness in that case. Here's a side-by-side view of the current [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election) on Stack Overflow vs. the Moderator Agreement page:

| SO Election page | Mod. Agreement |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Election page] | [image: Moderator Agreement] |

I think the font size of the Moderator Agreement page should be increased to make it easier to read.